# The inverse of the inverse Mellin transform of a function is equal to itself?

Tags: fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

As I know, The inverse of the inverse Laplace (or Fourier) transform of a function is equal to itself. Am I wrong?

and the inverse of the inverse Mellin transform of a function is equal to itself ?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse integral transform of an integral transform will get you back your original function *except possibly* for a set upon which the function of interest has a zero integral.

In particular, if a function has a finite number of discontinuities on any finite subinterval, you will lose information about those points because a discontinuity at a single point in a continuous neighborhood will not change the integral of that function.

Usually those points are not important, so we just refer to a transform and its inverse as essentially unique.